# Cmakelist working outside of Clion

Tags: cmake, clion, pkg-config

I've wanted to use Clion for awhile but I've always had trouble with Cmake. Armed with Cygwin, I've almost gotten this stupid thing to work.

The issue is while I can compile a cmake file from within a cygwin terminal, in Clion I am told it cannot find the library I want.

```
Error:A required package was not found
```

The cmakelist.txt file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(Test)

    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
    set(PKG_CONFIG_PATH /usr/lib/pkgconfig)
    set(PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE /usr/bin/pkg-config.exe)
    set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
    add_executable(Test ${SOURCE_FILES})

    INCLUDE(FindPkgConfig)

    pkg_check_modules(SDL2 REQUIRED "sdl2")

    MESSAGE(STATUS "SDL library:    " ${SDL2_LDFLAGS})

    TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(Test ${SDL2_LDFLAGS})
```

I have no idea if setting the variables PKG_CONFIG_PATH and others work, but they successfully build a makefile for my use in cygwin that builds correctly.

I've deleted the cache, remade the project and everything. It just refuses to work in Clion

Comment: "I can compile a cmake file from within a cygwin terminal, in Clion I am told it cannot find the library I want." makes no sense. You cannot compile a CMake file. What do you mean by CMake file?

Comment: I don't really know how else to put it. When I use cmake with the command "cmake ." it can compile my cmakelist.txt and then I can use the makefile to make my file. In Clion, it tells me it cannot find the SDL2 library, despite working outside of Clion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, your cmake config is unable to find SDL library. I found it better to use `find_package` command instead of `pkg_check_modules`.
In order to `find_package(SDL2)` to work, there must be `FindSDL2.cmake` module in directory, specified by `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` variable (usually, it is `cmake/Modules` directory inside your source tree).

`FindSDL2.cmake` is not a part of CMake, but you can find one online easily (check my own modules, for example: https://github.com/dragn/cmake-modules).
Refer to this doc for details: https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake:How_To_Find_Libraries.

Put `FindSDL2.cmake` to `cmake/Modules` directory and add this to your `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/Modules)
find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR})

...

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SDL2_LIBRARY})
```

NOTE: Sadly, it appears that Leonardo has not succeeded in finding volunteers for maintaining FindSDL2.cmake in SDL community: https://cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=14826.

Comment: I wish CMake was as simple as Makefiles. Thank you for your assistance, I can see Clion support was pushing this way as well. I'll give it a go and try making or modifying one of these.

Comment: @LordWindy CMake strives to do much more than Makefiles. When you write Makefile you write HOW to build, when you write CMake config, you write WHAT to build, and CMake will determine, how to do it (ideally, on any system with any compiler). I don't know if my explanation makes sense, just don't look at CMake as 'simply an alternative' to Makefiles, it is much more.